# What's the best practice in capitalization and punctuation when outputting program progress to STDERR?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I'm making some command line tools that output progress information as it runs to STDERR, like

```
found document
using cached version
analyzing

etc.
```

Should I output full sentences with capitalized first letters and periods at the end, or is this kind of terse uncapitalized output OK? What's the expert consensus on this?

Comment: I would just put ellipsis where required to differentiate starting events from finished events

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method to denote progress is a 'spinner'.  Here is one I implemented using `bash`.  The first parameter is the PID of the process you want to track and the second parameter is an optional message.  The PID is most easily passed via `$(pgrep <some_process_name>)`

```
#!/bin/bash

spinner() {
  [[ -n "$2" ]] && echo -n "$2 "

  if [[ ! $1 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
    return
  fi

  while [[ -d /proc/$1 ]]; do
    for c in '/' '-' '\' '|'; do
      printf "%c\b" "$c"
      sleep 0.1
    done
  done
  printf " \n"
}

du /usr > /dev/null 2>&1 & # Example program to monitor
spinner $(pgrep du) "Optional Message Here"
```

Comment: But you will have no inputs on what the process is doing... just that it is doing something.

Comment: @Twister obv it's not applicable to every application you can throw it at, but for ones where there is a lot of number crunching to get to a final answer, it works quite nicely. Besides, for those apps that produce output, there is no need for the spinner anyway because the user never has to guess if the process froze or if anything is actually happening; the data is right there on the screen.

Comment: agree. (btw I do like the idea of the spinner ;))